# How to set border color of certain Tkinter widgets?

Tags: python, colors, tkinter, tcl, border

I'm trying to change the background color of my Tkinter app, but for certain widgets it leaves a white border around the edges.

For example, this:

```
from tkinter import *

COLOR = "black"

root = Tk()
root.config(bg=COLOR)

button = Button(text="button", bg=COLOR)
button.pack(padx=5, pady=5)
entry = Entry(bg=COLOR, fg='white')
entry.pack(padx=5, pady=5)
text = Text(bg=COLOR, fg='white')
text.pack(padx=5, pady=5)

root.mainloop()
```

How can I set border colour of certain Tkinter widgets?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Just use

```
widget.config(highlightbackground=COLOR)
```

Furthermore, if you don't want that border at all, set the `highlightthickness` attribute to 0 (zero).

Comment: I wish this nice solution worked for all widgets, but `Combobox` widgets, for example, don't have a `highlightbackground` option. So the solution applied to a combobox raises `tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-highlightbackground"`.

Comment: How is highlightbackground related with the border of the background, that it is supposed to work even if widget is not highlighted?

Comment: @Marjan100 Any suggestions? I ran into that same problem. I ned to change the border colour not the `highlightbackground`

Comment: @Marjan100 Found [an answer](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-change-border-color-in-tkinter-widget/). Putting it in a frame with `bg=...` and then using `.pack(padx=..., pady=...)` on the widget.

Answer (score 5):

You have to set the two highlights (with and without focus) to have a continuous color.

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
e = Entry(highlightthickness=2)
e.config(highlightbackground = "red", highlightcolor= "red")
e.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: It works very well in ubuntu but when I tried same code in windows it doesn't work, it just give black border around it, can you please suggest any answer ?                      `self.historyButton = Button(self.M_Frame, text = 'History Logs', activebackground='#0892d0', activeforeground='white',
    bd=0, relief='solid', bg='#222222',fg='white', highlightbackground ='#0892d0', highlightcolor ='#0892d0',`
    font=('Flux Regular', 10, 'bold'), command = self.logHistoryToConsole)
  self.historyButton.grid(row=0, column = 0, padx=2)