# How do I change the border color of a tkinter widget?

Tags: python, tkinter, widget, ttk

I've been trying to configure the border colour of a widget in Tkinter, and I was wondering how to do that....

I've checked on StackOverflow, and it says that I should use the `configure` option and then set `highlightbackgroundcolor = {insert color here}`. I've tried that and nothing has worked. Can someone please show me a working sample of code so I can figure it out?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4320725/how-to-set-border-color-of-certain-tkinter-widgets. This says `highlightbackground` not `highlightbackgroundcolor`

Comment: @sshashank124 the highlight color is not the same as the border color.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way to change the border color of a widget, the border color is tied to the background color of the widget. Instead, you can turn off the border, and then use a frame widget where you can set the background color of the frame.

[image: screenshot]

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

label_border = tk.Frame(root, background="red")
label = tk.Label(label_border, text="This has a red border", bd=0)
label.pack(fill="both", expand=True, padx=1, pady=1 )

label_border.pack(padx=20, pady=20)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you. What is the reason for the difference between the background and the border?

Comment: If the border was the same color as the background, you wouldn't be able to see it.

Comment: i want to change only the border / highlight color. is it possible?

Comment: I still don't understand why it's not possible. changing only the border could be useful

Comment: @doofx: it's not possible because the widget simply doesn't have any options or functions to do it.