# Python game tkinter : change label color

Tags: python, tkinter, label, foreground

Hi i'm working a tictactoe multiplayer. When one client won a game, normaly each win label has to display in green.

This is the result that I want :

[image]

And this is the result that I get :

[image]

```
def check_row():
    list_symbols = []
    list_labels_temp = []
    winner = False
    win_symbol = ""
    for i in range(len(list_labels)):
        list_symbols.append(list_labels[i]["symbol"])
        list_labels_temp.append(list_labels[i])
        if (i + 1) % 3 == 0:
            if list_symbols[0] == list_symbols[1] == list_symbols[2]:
                if list_symbols[0] != "":
                    winner = True
                    win_symbol = list_symbols[0]

                    list_labels_temp[0]["label"].config(foreground="green", highlightbackground="green",
                                                        highlightcolor="green", highlightthickness=2)
                    list_labels_temp[1]["label"].config(foreground="green", highlightbackground="green",
                                                        highlightcolor="green", highlightthickness=2)
                    list_labels_temp[2]["label"].config(foreground="green", highlightbackground="green",
                                                        highlightcolor="green", highlightthickness=2)

            list_symbols = []
            list_labels_temp = []

    return [winner, win_symbol]
```

```
def check_col():
    winner = False
    win_symbol = ""
    for i in range(num_cols):
        if list_labels[i]["symbol"] == list_labels[i + num_cols]["symbol"] == list_labels[i + num_cols + num_cols][
            "symbol"]:
            if list_labels[i]["symbol"] != "":
                winner = True
                win_symbol = list_labels[i]["symbol"]
                print("winner")
                list_labels[i]["label"].config(foreground="green", highlightbackground="green",
                                               highlightcolor="green", highlightthickness=2)
                list_labels[i + num_cols]["label"].config(foreground="green", highlightbackground="green",
                                                          highlightcolor="green", highlightthickness=2)
                list_labels[i + num_cols + num_cols]["label"].config(foreground="green", highlightbackground="green",
                                                                     highlightcolor="green", highlightthickness=2)

    return [winner, win_symbol]
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hello, could you post your entire code? That way, we can do some debugging, and I can give you the final product. Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how-do-i-change-the-border-color-of-a-tkinter-widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59593020)