# How to set scrollText border in tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am new to tkinter.
My code likes this,

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import scrolledtext

Win = tkinter.Tk()
Text = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(Win)
Text.pack(padx=10,pady=10)
Win.mainloop()
```

As you can see,it only have the left border,top border.
However,it haven't right border and bottom border.

I have watched this [How to set border color of certain Tkinter widgets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4320725/how-to-set-border-color-of-certain-tkinter-widgets).
And I have tried `highlightbackground=color`,
the code is this

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import scrolledtext

Win = tkinter.Tk()
Text = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(Win)
Text.config(highlightbackground="black")
Text.pack(padx=10,pady=10)
Win.mainloop()
```

it also didn't work.it made no difference.

In this document:[tkinter.scrolledtext — Scrolled Text Widget](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.scrolledtext.html),I know that the constructor is the same as that of the `tkinter.Text` class.And I have seen [The Tkinter Text Widget](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm),But it didn't have config about the `tkinter.Text` border.

What should I do?

Comment: The literal answer to the question _"How to set scrollText border in tkinter?"_ is "the same as with any other widget, using the `borderwidth` and `relief` options". Have you tried using those?

Comment: @BryanOakley yes,OK.I try to use ```relief```.(The Tkinter Text Widget)[https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm].it has SUNKEN, RAISED, GROOVE, RIDGE, FLAT.but all of them can not have border in all the direction at the same time.

Comment: Correct - to get a sunken or raised relief requires that the top and left edges look different than the bottom and right edges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it only have the left border,top border.

Because the widget config is `relief="sunken"`,
So you can try `relief="solid"`.

So this is may solve your problem

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import scrolledtext

Win = tkinter.Tk()
Text = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(Win,relief="solid")
Text.pack(padx=10,pady=10)
Win.mainloop()
```

Comment: .....Why does ```relief="solid"``` can be used?(The Tkinter Text Widget)[https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm],this page even didn't mentioned it.

Comment: @BryanOakley It is in this page,https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm

Comment: Yes, and like I said, that page is incorrect. That is non official documentation.